# how to multiply all values from a column in a particular year in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to multiply all values in a particular year and push it to another column. With the code below I'm getting this error

```
TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", 'occurred at index
```

I'm getting `NaT` and `NaN` when I use shift(1). How can I get it to work?

```
def check_date():
    next_row = df.Date.shift(1)
    first_row = df.Date

    date1 = pd.to_datetime(first_row).year
    date2 = pd.to_datetime(next_row).year

    if date1 == date2:
        df['all_data_in_year'] = date1 * date2


df.apply(check_date(), axis=1)
```

DataSet:

```
    Date    Open    High    Low Last    Close   Total Trade Quantity    Turnover (Lacs)
31/12/10    816 824.5   807.3   815 818.45  1165987 9529.64
31/01/11    675 680 654 670.1   669.35  535039  3553.92
28/02/11    550 561.6   542 548.5   548.4   749166  4136.09
31/03/11    621.5   624.7   607.1   618 616.25  628572  3866
29/04/11    654.7   657.95  626 631 632.05  833213  5338.91
31/05/11    575 590 565.6   589.3   585.15  908185  5239.36
30/06/11    527 530.7   521.3   524 524.6   534496  2804.89
29/07/11    496.95  502.9   486 486.2   489.7   500743  2477.96
30/08/11    365.95  382.7   365 380 376.65  844439  3171.6
30/09/11    362.4   365.9   348.1   352 352.75  617537  2196.56
31/10/11    430 439.5   425 429.1   431.2   1033903 4493.97
30/11/11    349.05  354.95  344.15  348 350 686735  2404.1
30/12/11    353 355.9   340.1   340.1   342.75  740222  2565.39
31/01/12    443 451.45  428 445.5   446 1344942 5952.77
29/02/12    485.55  505.9   484 497 495.1   1011007 5004.46
30/03/12    421 436.45  418.4   432.5   432.95  867832  3740.04
30/04/12    410.35  419.4   406.85  414.3   414.05  418539  1733.81
31/05/12    362 363.05  351.2   359 358.3   840753  3000.41
29/06/12    385.05  395.3   382.9   388 389.75  1171690 4581.58
31/07/12    377.75  386 367.7   380.5   381.35  499246  1886.06
31/08/12    473.7   473.7   394.25  399 400.85  631225  2544.24
```

Comment: You're actually *calling* `check_date`... which doesn't return anything explicitly so returns `None`... when apply runs - it then tries to call `None`... you want `df.apply(check_date, axis=1)` and your function should be taking an argument for the row and actually return a result... However, this is almost certainly not how you want to do what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better is avoid loops (`apply` under the hood) and use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#sample Dataframe with sample datetimes
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='8m')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  

date1 = df.Date.shift(1).dt.year
date2 = df.Date.dt.year

df['all_data_in_year'] = np.where(date1 == date2, date1 * date2, np.nan)
print (df)
        Date  a  all_data_in_year
0 2017-04-30  0               NaN
1 2017-12-31  1         4068289.0
2 2018-08-31  2               NaN
3 2019-04-30  3               NaN
4 2019-12-31  4         4076361.0
5 2020-08-31  5               NaN
6 2021-04-30  6               NaN
7 2021-12-31  7         4084441.0
8 2022-08-31  8               NaN
9 2023-04-30  9               NaN
```

EDIT1:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby( pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year)['Close'].transform('prod')
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael. I don't want to hardcode the date in code. I want to run this code with any dataset which has timeseries of stocks. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @jason - Can you add some data sample - 5-6 row/ and expected output?

Comment: @jason there's no hard-coded date here... it's just generating example data... as long as your date column has your required date in it - it doesn't matter...

Comment: @JonClements Hi Jon. I've added the data. WHat code can I write group all year data and multiply all closing value to a new column? I really appreciate your help! Thanks :)

Comment: @jason - Not sure if understand. Do you think `df['new'] = df.groupby( pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year)['Close'].transform('prod')` ? What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael YES! THANK YOU :)